# Chess puzzle in which guarded pieces may not move

Tags: chess, board-games

Here's an interesting twist on the theme of chess puzzles, originally from the book *Caissa's Fairy Tales* by T. R. Dawson.

[image: board]

What is the minimum number of moves White needs to win this game from the position shown above (it is White's turn to play), given that **pieces cannot move while *guarded* (i.e. protected by other pieces of the same colour)**?

Comment: Can the king be checkmate by a piece that is guarded and can't move? If the rook is protected by the king, can't the black king just go by unarmed?

Comment: @stackreader No, the king can't move into check even if it would be checked by a 'guarded' piece. (If you like, think of it like this: the possibility of capturing the black king and winning the game outweighs any other considerations for a white piece.)

Comment: I would suggest adding that comment to the question as it is a big assumption to make that gaurded pieces cant move but they can still prevent the king moving into "checked" positions.

Comment: @gtwebb: It is already in standard chess rule. A king is not allowed to enter a square which is threatened by the opponent's piece. Think of discovered check, where a piece can't move because that will make the king in check. The enemy king still can't move to a square that the piece threatens.

Comment: I havent played chess since i was about 10 so i dont know discovered check, open check or anything other then check and checkmate. This isnt by standard chess rules or else there wouldnt be an additional rule about not moving when gaurding. @justhalf

Comment: @justhalf these types of checks are irrelevent.  The king is not moving to a square threatened by another piece because that piece cant move.  There might as well be a wall or another piece between those squares IMO.

Comment: Threat for king piece is not determined by whether the piece can move =)
See [this interesting discussion](https://www.chess.com/blog/run_along_now_honey/checks-by-pieces-pinned-to-their-king) on the same objection as yours, but in standard chess rules =D

Comment: Nice question. @justhalf The issue raised by stack reader & gtwebb is worth answering explicitly; given that the rules of chess are being altered, the alteration's scope might not be obvious to all solvers. Indeed *some* fairy conditions *do* affect check -- e.g. in Madrasi, paralysed units may not move *or* *check*.

Comment: If guarded pieces cannot move AND don't threaten, the Black King escapes on his first move past the Rook and White cannot win (further moves failing to free his pieces sufficiently). The problem infers that White can win and that the problem is minimizing the amount of moves to do so, therefore it's safe to infer that the pieces do threaten even when guarded. It would be interesting to see another problem with those rules, but this isn't it.

Comment: I feel like this question should be clarified to mention that the king is not under the restriction that "pieces which are guarded cannot move".

Comment: @Shufflepants But it is under that (vacuous) restriction. There are no other black pieces on the board, so the black king is never guarded and therefore can always move (until it gets checkmated).

Comment: @justhalf: That interesting discussion doesn't take too long to get to the real point: all of the rules that disallow movement are ultimately expressions of "if you made that move, your king could be taken next term" -- it's not really that the piece *can't* move, but doing so would throw the game away. A variant that actually makes it so pieces *really* can't move requires clarification if you still want to forbid kings to move into the squares that their ordinary movement would threaten.

Comment: @randal'thor oh, woops, I guess I misread the solutions from others. Never mind. For some reason I thought they had the white king moving first.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer:

> 4 moves
>  C4,Kc5, Kb5, Ra7
>  you need to block the rook from protecting the king, so the king can block the rook from protecting the rook. At which point the second rook can move to check mate.

Comment: The black king would be in a position to capture a piece and stay gaurded before the rook can move to a7. Or the king could easy move behind the rook or pawn.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to just do `kc5, kb5, Ra7`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Matthew0898 I'm assuming he's counting the b4 rook as "guarding" the king. Hence why c4 is necessary.

Comment: @DennisMeng Yeah, I totally missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

4 moves

> 1. c4  Ka2 {Only legal moves}
>  2. Kc5 Ka3 {Black moves to stall inevitable}
>  3. Kb5 Ka2 {White king frees b7 rook to move}
>  4. Ra7 #

Comment: Why would 3. Kb6 be illegal?

Comment: @user2390246 It's not illegal, but losing the rook lead to stalemate, since after black captures the rook, the pawn would be the only legal piece to move. After c5, white would no longer have any moves as every piece would be guarded.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say, why would 3. Kb5 be illegal?

Comment: @user2390246 No reason. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Going hamateur has a good answer but I will go with the possibility that the pawn is actually in the enemy zone and not initial position.(I might be wrong but it was not mentioned what side of the board the white player started)

> It's possible in 2 moves. pawn goes down 1 and transform in a queen, then move to b2 for checkmate.

Comment: The letters are included on the diagram in the question. White always starts from rank 1 and Black from rank 8.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that. Thanks for the info. Does no accepted answers yet mean there is still a better answer out there? 4 move is the best I could find so far. Should I keep looking?

Comment: Generally, no accepted answers yet just means I'm slow at accepting answers :-) I'm pretty sure GH's answer is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

OP mentioned that

```
pieces cannot move while guarded
```

In such a case both rooks can't move because they are guarding each other. Unless OP  meant that pieces can't move to such a position where they can check the Black King while being guarded by the teammates (like the rook at b4 can't move to b2 because it is being guarded by the rook at b7). Considering latter to be the case...

The minimum number of moves is

> 1

with two possibilities either

> rook at b4 moves a4

or

> rook at b7 moves to a7

Comment: But the rooks can't move! Just like you said, initially both rooks are guarding each other. This isn't doable in one move.

Comment: @randal'thor ok so former is the case, but then we will never have those rooks moving because they are always guarding each other. Even the king can't move because he is being protected by rook at b4.The only unguarded member is the pawn. White won't win this way.

Comment: Yes, the rooks can't move until something comes between them, and the king can't move until something comes between it and the rook at b4. To see how White wins, you can read [Going hamateur's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44280/5373).

Comment: @randal'thor You are right, I thought it over, the king would have to cut off the rooks from each other, also king is not protected by the rook he is rather being supported by the rook at b4. It was a nice puzzle. Cheers!!!

Answer (score -1):

THIS ANSWER ASSUMES THAT IF A PIECE CANT MOVE IT CAN'T THREATEN

With this assumption

> White cant win

If somebody could help me embed a chess game that would help to visualize but white basically has two options

Option 1

> Get king to B5 to free rook at B7 or

Option 2

> Get king to B6 to free rook at B4.

First 2 turns for white are

> c4, Kc5

First 2 turns for black are

> Ka2, Ka3

Now

> White moves KB5, Black takes the rock at B4, since the King is frozen by the pawn this is a legal move and black has check mate.

Or

> White moves Bb6 and again black takes rook at B4.  This leaves only the white pawn free as the king and rook cannot be separated so black wins again.

And

> Since white eventually has to free one of the rooks to win, black can just stay within one square of B4 and he can win as outlined above regardless of any other delaying moves the white king makes.

Comment: How would the black king capture the b4 rook, if it's protected?

Comment: @HerbWolfe I rewrote to make it clearer.  The king can capture the rook at B4 because the pawn is guarding the king (so the king can't move).  You could argue this means the rook is unguarded but it doesn't really matter because he doesn't have a chance to move before the black king captures the rook.

Comment: A king can't move into a square which is guarded/threatened by other piece, regardless whether that piece can move or not. (think of discovered check, where a piece can't move because that will cause the king to be checked. The enemy king still can't move into the square threatened by the piece)

Comment: Could I ask why the downvotes?  Given the information in the question assuming a gaurded piece cant check seems valid to me in which case i believe this is the right answer.

Comment: @justhalf not sure what open check means if the piece cant move i dont see any reason why it should be able to check the king.  White has no legal way to attack the square the king moves to.

Comment: @gtwebb: Sorry, I meant discovered check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovered_attack

Comment: Also, someone else apparently previously has discussed your objection, but in standard chess rules: https://www.chess.com/blog/run_along_now_honey/checks-by-pieces-pinned-to-their-king =D

Comment: @justhalf the article makes sense a king cant move within range of a pinned piece because that pinned piece would capture the  king and win before the opposition has a chance to attack your king.  These pieces arent pinned, they are under a made up rule that they cant move while gaurded.  Very different from being pinned based on the fact that they need to protect their king.

Comment: @gtwebb Yes, its a made up rule.  But nothing in that rule states that locked pieces does not threathen squares - that's your invention.

Comment: Nothing states things either way, I like the ingenuity of considering that element of things. However, as stated elsewhere, the problem strongly infers that White always wins and it's just a case of working out the fastest way to do so. This means that the amended rule cannot be enforced in this manner.

Comment: I really don't see why this is getting so many down votes. Despite being present @randal'thor has not clarified in the question that this is not a valid interpretation of the rules and the answer was here before he stated it in a comment.  With the assumption that a piece can't threaten if it can't move this is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @gtwebb: Ok, I concede on this after seeing [Rosie F's comment](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44278/chess-puzzle-in-which-guarded-pieces-may-not-move?noredirect=1#comment133093_44278) that it might not be obvious to some. +1 for finding a loophole in the question!